# onAuthStateChanged executing before any change is made

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want my page to navigate to homescreen after the user has logged in ( through firebase auth) and display username from the email used to sign in. For this purpose I am using onAuthStateChanged to navigate to hme screen my my website is navigating to homescreen as soon as the login page is displayed (without user loging in).
ere is my code -

```
 import styled from "styled-components";
 import { useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
 import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 import { auth, provider} from "../firebase";
 import { selectUserName, 
    selectUserPhoto, 
    setUserLoginDetails,
    setSignOutState
} from "../features/user/userSlice";
 import { getAuth, signInWithPopup,GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged} from 
 "firebase/auth";
 import { useEffect } from "react";


 const Header = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);

useEffect(() =>{
    onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user) => {
        
        if(user) {
            setUser(user);
            navigate("/home");
        }
    });
}, [userName])

const handleAuth = () =>{
    if(!userName){
        signInWithPopup(auth,provider)
        .then((result) =>{
            setUser = (result.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message)
        });
    }   else if(userName) {
        
            SignOut(auth)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(setSignOutState());
                navigate.push("/Login");
            })
            .catch((err) => alert(err.message));
    }
};

const setUser = (user) =>{
    dispatch(
        setUserLoginDetails({
            name: user.displayname,
            email: user.email,
            photo: user.photoURL,
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Have you logged in before? Because from your code, it is redirecting you to the homepage because there is already a logged-in user. Is there a user when you console.log(user)?

Comment: No I haven't logged in before, there is no user in console, and moreover in my return section, i have used conditional statement so condition statement for no user logged in is only being executed.